# How to convert these lines into one per line?

Tags: xml, record

This question is really important since I need to present the data to my supervisor asap.

I have a list of records in this format:

```
Name
Date
Place

Name
Date
Place
```

I want these records into one line like this:

```
Name,Date,Place
Name,Date,Place
```

How can I achieve this under Linux by using awk or sed easily?

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Gnu AWK`, you can do something like this -

```
gawk -v RS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Name
Date
Place

Name
Date
Place
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk -v RS='\n\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2,$3}' file
Name,Date,Place
Name,Date,Place
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v OFS=',' '$1=$1' data.txt
Name,Date,Place
Name,Date,Place
```

- `RS=''` multi-line record
- `OFS=','` output fields SEP by `,`
- `$1=$1` force rebuild fields

Comment: Much better solution than mine and it works on both `awk` and `gawk`. +1